# Ошибка - не найден класс

Tags: laravel, mvc, controller

Laravel 7.13 - Сделал форму добавления проекта . 
Файл ProjectController.php

```
class ProjectController extends Controller
{
    public function index() {
        //
    }
    public function show($id) {
       //
    }
    public function create() {
        return view('project.add');
    }
    public function store()
    {
        $input = App\Project::all();

        Projects::create($input);

        return redirect('project');
    }

}
```

Но после того как нажимаю на кнопку добавить проект, выскакивает ошибка 
`Error
Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Projects' not found`.
Где я не накосячил ?

Answer (score 0):

```
Use App\Project;
```

необходимо было добавить